# There is no bind-address var on my MySQL server

Tags: mysql, networking, ip

I tried to cinfigure my MySQL server to make it possible to connect to it from different machines. I was told that there should be a variable called "bind-address" and it's value should be 0.0.0.0. OK. First I can't find my.cnf file, only my.ini, my-large.ini and so on. Second, I typed >mysql --help to see variables' values and there were no bind-address var at all! What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`bind-address` is a [client option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_bind-address), not a server option. The server should be listening at 0.0.0.0 by default.